# Using extractors to parse text files

Tags: scala

I'm trying to improve a CSV parsing routine and feel that extractors could be useful here but can't figure them out. Suppose there's a file with user ids and emails:

```
1,alice@alice.com
2,bob@bob.com
3,carol@carol.com
```

If the `User` class is defined as `case class User(id: Int, email: String)` everything is pretty easy with something like

```
lines map { line =>
  line split "," match {
    case Array(id, email) => User(id.toInt, email)
  }
}
```

What I don't understand is how to deal with the case where `User` class can have complex properties e.g

```
case class Email(username: String, host: string)
case class User(id: Int, email: Email)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, an example using a custom Extractor.

```
// 1,Alice,21212,Baltimore,MD" -> User(1, Alice, Address(21212, Baltimore, MD))
```

Define a custom Extractor that creates the objects out of given String:

```
object UserExtractor {
    def unapply(s: String) : Option[User] = try {
        Some( User(s) )
    }
    catch {
        // bettor handling of bad cases
        case e: Throwable => None
    }
}
```

Case classes to hold the data with a custom apply on Comapnion object on User:

```
case class Address(code: String, cit: String, county: String)

case class User(id: Int, name: String, address: Address)
object User {
    def apply(s: String) : User = s.split(",") match {
        case Array(id, name, code, city, county) => User(id.toInt, name, Address(code, city, county)  )
    }
}
```

Unapplying on a valid string (in the example valid means the correct number of fields).

```
"1,Alice,21212,Baltimore,MD" match { case UserExtractor(u) => u }
res0: User = User(1,Alice,Address(21212,Baltimore,MD))
```

More tests could be added with more custom apply methods.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a regular expression to extract the contents of the email address.  Maybe something like this:

```
val lines = Vector(
  "1,alice@alice.com",
  "2,bob@bob.com",
  "3,carol@carol.com")

case class Email(username: String, host: String)
case class User(id: Int, email: Email)

val EmailRe = """(.*)@(.*\.com)""".r  // substitute a real email address regex here

lines.map { line =>
  line.split(",") match {
    case Array(id, EmailRe(uname, host)) => User(id.toInt, Email(uname, host))
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look very flexible to me.  With all the new top level domains hitting soon, I don't think you'd want to match on ".com", or any other TLD for that matter.

Comment: @James: Clearly you would want to substitute your own regex for email addresses.  They are complex, and you can easily find one with a quick search online.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a single RegexExtractor :

```
val lines = List(
  "1,alice@alice.com",
  "2,bob@bob.com",
  "3,carol@carol.com"
)

case class Email(username: String, host: String)
case class User(id: Int, email: Email)


val idAndEMail = """^([^,]+),([^@]+)@(.+)$""".r
```

and define a function that transforms a line to the an User :

```
def lineToUserWithMail(line: String) : Option[User] = 
  idAndEMail.findFirstMatchIn(line) map { 
case userWithEmail(id,user,host) => User(id.toInt, Email(user,host) )
  }
```

Applying the function to all lines

```
lines flatMap lineToUserWithMail
//res29: List[User] = List(User(1,Email(alice,alice.com)), User(2,Email(bob,bob.com)), User(3,Email(carol,carol.com)))
```

Alternatively you could implement custom Extractors on the case classe by adding an unnapply Method. But for that case it wouldn't be worth the pain.

Here is an example for unapply

```
class Email(user:String, host:String)
object Email {
def unapply(s: String) : Option[(String,String)] = s.split("@") match {
    case Array(user, host) => Some( (user,host) )
    case _ => None 
}
```

}

```
"bob@bob.com" match {
case Email(u,h) => println( s"$u , $h" )
}
// prints bob , bob.com
```

A word of warning on using Regex to parse CSV-data. It's not as easy as you might think, i would recommend to use a CSV-Reader as http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/ which handles some nasty edge cases out of the box.

Comment: Well, I guess I've asked the wrong question by trying to think of the simplest example possible. The user structure contains huge number  of fields so extracting everything with a single regex is infeasible. Its always possible to just access the array by index but I'd rather use some clever trick with extractors. It seems rather hard to combine them for something like `"1,Alice,21212,Baltimore,MD" -> User(1, Alice, Address(21212, Baltimore, MD))`

Comment: Ok, it would be possible by defining several unapply methods on the companion Objects. i will add an example.